# MSSQL Paginate results with a sum function

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

I have a table with rows that have a number of clicks for a category, for a specific day. Like this:

```
ID  CatID   Date                 Count
1   DADB    2011-11-04 00:00:00      3
2   DCBC    2011-11-04 00:00:00      9
3   DADH    2011-11-04 00:00:00      9
```

So to display the total count for each of the categories between two dates I would do something like this:

```
SELECT WebClicksCategory.CatID, sum(WebClicksCategory.Count) as Count
FROM [Web].[dbo].[WebClicksCategory]
WHERE Date >= '2011-04-17 00:00:00.000'
AND Date <= '2012-04-17 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY WebClicksCategory.CatID
ORDER BY Count desc
```

However if I want to paginate these results and do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT  row_number() OVER (order by Count) AS rownum, 
WebClicksCategory.CatID, sum(WebClicksCategory.Count) as Count 
FROM [Web].[dbo].[WebClicksCategory]
WHERE Date >= '2011-04-17 00:00:00.000'
AND Date <= '2012-04-17 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY WebClicksCategory.CatID
) AS A
WHERE A.rownum BETWEEN (50) AND (200)
```

But I get a 'Column WebClicksCategory.Count is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause' error. Is there another way to paginate the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with including the aggregate in the , but actually from including it in the OVER clause:

```
( SELECT  row_number() OVER (order by Count) AS rownum,
```

So what I might suggest is:

```
SELECT rownum, CatID, Count FROM 
( SELECT  row_number() OVER (order by Count) AS rownum, CatID, Count
FROM 
  ( SELECT WebClicksCategory.CatID, sum(WebClicksCategory.Count) as Count 
    FROM [Web].[dbo].[WebClicksCategory]
    WHERE Date >= '2011-04-17 00:00:00.000'
    AND Date <= '2012-04-17 00:00:00.000'
    GROUP BY WebClicksCategory.CatID
  ) AS B
) AS A
WHERE A.rownum BETWEEN (50) AND (200)
```